# How to Serve Flask inside container in production

Tags: docker, kubernetes, flask, webserver

How to create docker image for Flask applications and serve it for production with scalability

I need to deploy my flask app using docker container. As per docker principles it is recommended to run only one process inside a container.

But in Flask apps it is recommended uses wsgi servers which will spawn multiple process.

And flask inbuilt server is not recommended to use during production.
I checked lot of git repos and tutorials but most of them are using inbuilt flask server or gunincorn. But in gunicorn they are using multiples process

Can anybody suggest how to serve flask app in this case

Comment: What have you done so far? what you have tried? where you face the issue?https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi Adii,This question is regarding how to create a flask app container for production environment not regarding issue with flask or docker

Comment: [gunicorn starts a single master process that gets forked, and the resulting child processes are the workers.](https://medium.com/building-the-system/gunicorn-3-means-of-concurrency-efbb547674b7) - I’d suggest following the examples that you’ve found using gunicorn.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the gunicorn for falsk and write the docker file and create docker images for example

```
FROM python:3.6
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install flask gunicorn
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8000", "app"]
```